# Fix missing performance counters

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revive SQL Server 2008R2 performance counters?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13733/how-to-revive-sql-server-2008r2-performance-counters)

On one machine, I have an instance of SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise, Visual Studio 2010 and VS 11 Developer Preview. I tried to install SQL 2012 RC0, but it failed due to come conflict with VS 11, so I removed it. Unfortunately, the process seems to broken performance counters. They're missing from permon, as well as `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`.

On another machine, I upgraded from SQL 2005 Standard to SQL 2008R2, and perf counters also vanished there in the process.

Is there anything I can do to restore the counters, short of removing and then re-installing SQL Server?

Comment: FYI, I'm going to flag http://serverfault.com/q/341519/4955 for migration to here. This question will be a duplicate then. Pop into chat if you want to discuss http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap