# How to revive SQL Server 2008 R2 performance counters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, perfmon

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer on Windows 7 x64, as the default instance. For some reason, SQL Server's performance counters seem to have disappeared. `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters` returns zero rows.

I tried running `lodctr /T:perf-MSSQLSERVERsqlctr.ini`. Although it completed without errors, it didn't fix anything, even after restarting the Remote Registry service. In fact, the counters are now missing from perfmon. `unlodctr MSSQLSERVER` still says that the counters are not installed, but `lodctr /Q:MSSQLSERVER` says they're present and enabled. Regular Windows and .NET counters are working fine.

In the Windows Error log, I'm seeing Error 8317:

> Cannot query value 'First Counter' associated with registry key
>   'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER\Performance'. SQL
>   Server performance counters are disabled.

I suspect the problem may have been triggered by an installation of SQL 2012 RC0 that failed. Any suggestions for how to recover, short of reinstalling SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: You mean "Visual Studio 11" (not "2011"?)

Comment: Yes, VS 11. The problem with the question on serverfault is that none of the posted answers resolved the issue. I'm hoping DBA-oriented users might be able to provide more useful help.

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with `lodctr /R`, it will rebuild all performance counters from informations stored in registry.

Comment: In my case there were more counters missing, not only SQL Server's. `lodctr /R` did the trick and restored them all. Thank you very much for the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Read through this:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-counter-collection-problems)

The exact instructions are not 100% correct. You need to do this, assuming you are using the default instance:

```
unlodctr MSSQLSERVER
lodctr perf-MSSQLSERVERsqlperf.ini
lodctr /T:MSSQLSERVER
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I found that symbolfile path in my perf-MSSQLSERVERsqlctr.ini was incorrect. I fixed it, executed lodctr /T:perf-MSSQLSERVERsqlctr.ini, lodctr perf-MSSQLSERVERsqlctr.ini and restarted SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Missing performance counters is recurring issue.

Some known solutions are listed here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214203627/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/varund/archive/2010/06/25/sql-server-missing-performance-counters-a-consolidated-list-of-known-issues.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Performance Counters for SQL Server are DISABLED or the registry entries for the performance counters are corrupted.

`lodctr /E:MSSQLSERVER` will reload the performance counter registry settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 32-bit version of SQL Server on a 64-bit installation of Windows you need to use the 32-bit version of Performance Monitor to view the counters as explained in [this MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/docast/archive/2014/08/25/issues-with-sql-data-collection-using-performance-monitor-user-defined-data-collector-set.aspx). Do so using either of these methods:

1. Run `perfmon.exe` from the `%windir%\SysWOW64` folder
2. Run the command `mmc /32 perfmon.msc`

Also, make sure you're running SQL Server with the latest Service Pack and Hotfixes.  [MSKB article 2708726](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2708726) describes an issue where Performance Monitor .dll files don't get updated properly when applying updates to SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2012.